# Understanding the lifecycle of a connection managed by PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager in Apache HTTP client

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, keep-alive, httpconnection

I felt very confused after reading the [Connection Management](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) doc of the Apache HTTP components module, and also a few other resources on connection keep alive strategy and connection eviction policy.

There are a bunch of adjectives used in there to describe the state of a connection like `stale`, `idle`, `available`, `expired` and `closed` etc. There isn't a lifecycle diagram describing how a connection changes among these states.

My confusion mainly arose from below situation.

I set a `ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy` that provides a `KeepAliveDuration` of 5 seconds via below code snippet.

```java
        ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy keepAliveStrategy = ( httpResponse, httpContext ) -> {
            HeaderElementIterator iterator = 
                 new BasicHeaderElementIterator( httpResponse.headerIterator( HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE ) );
            while ( iterator.hasNext() )
            {
                HeaderElement header = iterator.nextElement();
                if ( header.getValue() != null && header.getName().equalsIgnoreCase( "timeout" ) )
                {
                    return Long.parseLong( header.getValue(), 10) * 1000;
                }
            }
            return 5 * 1000;
        };
        this.client = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig( requestConfig )
                .setMaxConnTotal( 500 )    
                .setMaxConnPerRoute( 500 )
                .setConnectionManager( this.cm )  
                .setKeepAliveStrategy( keepAliveStrategy )
                .build();
```

The server I am talking to does support connections to be kept alive. When I printed out the pool stats of the connection manager after executing around ~200 requests asynchronously in a single batch, below info was observed.

```
Total Stats:
-----------------
Available: 139
Leased: 0
Max: 500
Pending: 0
```

And after waiting for 30 seconds (by then the keep-alive timeout had long been exceeded), I started a new batch of the same HTTP calls. Upon inspecting the connection manager pool stats, the number of available connections are is still 139.

**Shouldn't it be zero since the keep-alive timeout had been reached?** The [PoolStats Java doc](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/pool/PoolStats.html) states that `Available` is "the number of idle persistent connections". Are idle persistent connections considered alive?

I think [Apache HttpClient: How to auto close connections by server's keep-alive time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697290/apache-httpclient-how-to-auto-close-connections-by-servers-keep-alive-time) is a close hit but hope some expert could give an insightful explanation about the lifecycle of a connection managed by `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`.

Some other general questions:

1. Does the default connection manager used in `HttpAsyncClients.createdDefault()` handle connection keep-alive strategy and connection eviction on its own?
2. What are the requirements/limitations that could call for implementing them on a custom basis? Will they contradict each other?

Answer (score 3):

Documenting some of my further findings which might partially fulfill as an answer.

1. Whether using a `ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy` to set a timeout on the keep alive session or not, the connections will end up in the TCP state of `ESTABLISHED`, as inspected via `netstat -apt`. And I observed that they are automatically recycled after around 5 minutes in my Linux test environment.
2. When NOT using a `ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy`, upon a second request batch the established connections will be reused.
3. When using a `ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy` and its timeout has NOT been reached, upon a second request batch the established connections will be reused.
4. When using a `ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy` and its timeout has been exceeded, upon a second request batch, the established connections will be recycled into the `TIME_WAIT` state, indicating that client side has decided to close the connections.
5. This recycling can be actively exercised by performing `connectionManager.closeExpiredConnections();` in a separate connection evicting thread, which will lead the connections into `TIME_WAIT` stage.

I think the general observation is that `ESTABLISHED` connections are deemed as `Available` by the connection pool stats, and the connection keep alive strategy with a timeout does put the connections into expiry, but it only takes effect when new requests are processed, or when we specifically instruct the connection manager to close expired connections.

[TCP state diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg) from Wikipedia for reference.